# Font Color not setting in Container on DOTNETNUKE

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

The header and body have the correct background color but the fonts look gray.  I am running on DOTNETNUKE version 4.9.0 and 4.9.1 and Windows 2003.

Thanks

test.htm

```
<body class="border">
    <div class="PhilosophyHeader" runat="server">[ACTIONS][ICON]  [TITLE]</div>
    <div id="ContentPane" runat="server" class="PhilosophyBody"></div>
</body>
```

container.css

```
.PhilosophyHeader
{
    color: #FF0000;
    font: normal normal bold 100%/normal serif;
    border: thin #CC9900;
    background-color: #CC9900;
}

.PhilosophyBody
{
    background-color: #800000;
    color: #CC9900;
}

.border
{
    border: thin #FFFF00 solid;
}
```

edit: Removed `<header>`, it did not effect problem.

Answer: The problem was a combination of tags not matched and use of the same name in two containters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by a variety of problems.  Without having a website to view it's going to be difficult for anyone here to answer your question.

One of the easiest ways to diagnose CSS problems like this is to use the Firefox extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Inspect the text that is appearing gray and see exactly what styles are being applied to it.  The styles are shown in a hierarchy from bottom to top.

I don't know if you just formatted your example this way for Stack Overflow, but you should not be including the `<head>` or `<body>` tags in your container.  DotNetNuke will automatically load the CSS file called `container.css` if it is in the same directory as your container HTML or ASCX file.  It will additionally load any CSS file that has the same name as the container being loaded.  For example, if you have a container called `MyContainer.ascx`, DotNetNuke will automatically load `container.css` and `MyContainer.css`, provided they exist.